# Timed Content Size issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a hidden CSS Class that fade in after a few seconds. Here is what I did:

JS Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ $(".timedcontent3").fadeIn(500); }, 5000);        
});
```

CSS Code:

```
.timedcontent3 {
display: none;
}
```

Everything works great... However when I try to put in the shortcode of an optin form or a counter in the container there is a weird size issue as you can see here: https://gesund-schnell-gewicht-zunehmen.de/test/

Any ideas what causes the problem an how I can fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: One person's "weird size issue" is another's "artistic masterpiece". If you would, please describe exactly what you want to achieve and what you are getting instead.

Comment: I saw that your "soon-flip-inner"-spans  gets a 0.1em width. That causes the problem. Can you check this?